# Merge [tagging] to [tags]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, tagging

We have both [tags](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) here on Meta. Seems redundant. Can the smaller tag be synonymised?

Answer (score 1):

[tags](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) refers to questions about the tag itself, whereas the one question (other than this one) labelled [tagging](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) talks about proper tagging itself. While the [tagging](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) tag is definitely uncommon, I don't think they're redundant to each other.